# Combining elements of two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
lst1 = ['a', 'b']
lst2 = ['c', 'd', 'e']
```

I want to make combinations like this:

```
[['a', 'c'], ['a', 'd'], ['a', 'e'], ['b', 'c'], ['b', 'd'], ['b', 'e']]
```

Kindly help me with this. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you need a list of lists or is [an iterable of tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) acceptable as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst1 = ['a', 'b']
>>> lst2 = ['c', 'd', 'e']
>>> itertools.product(lst1, lst2)
<itertools.product object at 0x7f3571488280>
>>> list(itertools.product(lst1, lst2))
[('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('a', 'e'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('b', 'e')]
>>> x = list(itertools.product(lst1, lst2))
>>> [list(y) for y in x]
[['a', 'c'], ['a', 'd'], ['a', 'e'], ['b', 'c'], ['b', 'd'], ['b', 'e']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I leave you an example without using libraries too.

Script:

```
lst1 = ['a', 'b']
lst2 = ['c', 'd', 'e']
lst3 = []

for item_lst1 in lst1:
    for item_lst2 in lst2:
        lst3.append([item_lst1, item_lst2])

print(lst3)
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'c'], ['a', 'd'], ['a', 'e'], ['b', 'c'], ['b', 'd'], ['b', 'e']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the job for you.

```
   list1 = ['a', 'b']
   list2 = ['c', 'd', 'e']
    
   req_list = [[x, y] for x in list1 for y in list2]
```

This type of combining is called cartesian product or cross product.